# Problem when creating a new Discussion Board item using PowerShell. the item Name for the new item will have the following format "ITEMID_.000"

Tags: 2013, list, powershell, administration, discussion-board

I am working on a Discussion Board list inside SharePoint 2013 on-premise. The Discussion Board list is inside a Team Site collection which have the publishing infrastructure features enabled (both at the site collection and the site level).

We have a couple of old announcements inside our emails and documents which we need to upload inside the Discussion Board list.

so I wrote the following PowerShell script, to add old announcements to the SharePoint Discussion Board list:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://servername/"  
$list = $web.Lists["News & Announcements"]  
$newItem = $List.AddItem()   
$newItem["Title"] = "Test announcment"  
$newItem["Name"] = "Test announcment" 
$newItem["Body"] = "test body"  
$newItem["Modified"] = "9/3/2015"
$newItem["Created"] = "8/3/2015"  
$user = $web.EnsureUser("\staging.user")  
$newItem["Editor"] = $user  
$newItem["Author"] = $user  
$newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

Now this PowerShell script will create a new Discussion item with all the specified data correctly, but when I open the new Discussion item I have noted that the item's Name will have the following format "ITEMID_.000", instead of showing the item's title or name (Test Announcement in my case) as when creating a new Discussion item using the UI. here is the result of running the above PowerShell script:

[image]

When I click on the item compliance details for the item , I got this where it clearly state that the name is wrong:

[image]

So can anyone advice what is going on? And how I can show the Discussion title instead of "ITEMID_.000"?

Thanks

Comment: I executed the commands, it worked perfectly

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli now i am using a team site collection inside an on-premise, and it have the publishing infrastructure enabled (both inside the site collection & and inside the site levels),, is this the case at your end also ?

Comment: I know I know. In this case `$list` = `$List`, but you shouldn't change the case when trying to refer to the same variable.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis can you advice more on this please???

Comment: Are all other values set properly? Is it just the Title that's not working?

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis i think the problem is that the name is not being populated correctly... check my edit , where i click on the item's compliance details and i got that the item name is wrong "265_.000" as shown on my question

Comment: Please check the following for me:
`$web = Get-SPWeb "http://servername/"` 
`$list = $web.Lists["News & Announcements"]`
`$list.BaseType`

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis GenericList ..

Comment: @johnG, sorry I was thinking about one thing and typing another. I meant `BaseTemplate`  not `BaseType`

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis no problem basetemplate is DiscussionBoard..actually this is an out of the box announcmentlist

Comment: And that, my friend, is why the title is not working :) I'll write up an answer in a minute.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis it is my fault i mistype my list type,, i am using discussion board and not an announcement list.. i have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PaulStrupeikis got it correct. So for powershell, you need to use it as below:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://servername/" 
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("News & Announcements")
if($list -ne $null)
{ 
$newTopic = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateNewDiscussion($list, "Test announcment"); 
$newTopic["Body"] = "test body";
$newTopic["Modified"] = "9/3/2015"
$newTopic["Created"] = "8/3/2015"  
$user = $web.EnsureUser("\staging.user")  
$newTopic["Editor"] = $user  
$newTopic["Author"] = $user  
$newTopic.UpdateOverwriteVersion() 

Write-Host $newTopic.Title " discussion topic is created successfully"
}
else
{ 
Write-Host "List does not exists." 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

John G, your News & Announcements list is using `DiscussionBoard` template instead of `Announcements` template. Discussion board is a thread container and the discussions within are threads. You cannot set the title of a thread like that. If you still want to be using `DiscussionBoard` template, you can create new 'announcements' (well, technically - discussions) by using the following line of code:

`SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussion(SPList, String)`

More on this [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createnewdiscussion.aspx)

In case you want an announcement list, you should create a new list based on Announcements template. In that case your original code should work fine.

Comment: you know it is my fault,, i am actually using Discussion Board list not announcement list .... but since our customer asked us to name it "announcement" so i mistype it .. i updated my original question

Comment: so using SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussion(SPList, String) can i set the item's modified, created,author, editor fields ?

Comment: i am really sorry about the mistype... so now i am not sure if i can pass the editor,author, modified, created fields using SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussion ??seems it only allow passing title..

Comment: You wouldn't believe how often this happens :) Refer to an answer below for the code how to set other values (haven't tested it tho).